# Mount remote share via VPN connection (Windows to Windows)

Tags: windows, vpn, mount

I have a remote Windows 2008 Server (hosted on Rackspace Cloud).  I would like to have multiple VPN clients to connect and mount a shared drive.

I was able to set up the VPN, but I can't seem to figure out how to mount the shares.  Also, since I am VPNing into a single machine (not really on a network), should I configure my VPN in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to mount that share in a linux-client or windows-client?

Comment: Mount or map? If you want to map it to a drive letter, you can use the "net use" command

Answer (score 1):

If you can access your server with an IP, you should be able to connect/mount a share if your firewalls are configured properly.

On Windows you can just klick "Map Network Drive" at the "Computer", enter your servers IP-Address and the sharename like this: \\server-ip-address\share

On Linux, you can use mount, but you need additional packages (cifs-mount and samba-client).
Then you can mount your share with `mount -t cifs -o user //192.168.0.1/share /mount/point`. A better and complete explanation for this can be found [here](http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susesambacifs.html) (works for other distributions like debian too)

**Edit**:
As the link is dead, here is a link to a cached version at the web archive:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130209134816/http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susesambacifs.html

Comment: The Linux link is dead.

Comment: I added a link to a cached version from the good ol' web archive ;)